# How to make drag/drop image responsive in Adobe experience manager?

Tags: xml, image, aem, responsive

I am using `Classic UI` to add `Image component` and `drag/drop` the images. But some images with large width expands the width of the component. What changes I need to make to make sure the size of the image is `equal` to that of the component?

Here is Home specific content.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
  jcr:title="Front page"
  sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parbase"
  componentGroup="Group 1"/>
```

Comment: Probably setting the width of the image should fix it? Setting `width: 100%;` in the CSS should make the image fit the container that it is currently in.

Comment: There is no css for the container. What class should I take into consideration to apply this style. Image is drag/drop not hardcoded

Comment: the width should be set for the img tag. For e.g., `img { width: 100%; }`.

Comment: It somwhat worked. The width is equal to size of component but not the height. Adding height to 100% did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: All the images the page with is changing to 100%, and there is no class for this image where I can target this component